# How to handle 4 arrays with equal number of objects to insert into mysql database using pdo prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to insert shares data of my company into mysql database. I have four arrays of the type as follows:

```
$lot_number = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$serial_begin = array(1, 51, 101, 151, 201);
$serial_last = array(50, 100, 150, 200, 250);
$identifier = array(FA2567, FA2568, FA2569, FA2570, FA2571);
```

I am trying to construct an array of arrays as follows:

```
$data = array($lot_number, $serial_begin, $serial_last, $identifier);
```

And using PDO prepared statement with the following script:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO shares_fclass 
                        (lot_number, serial_begin, serial_last, identifier) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    foreach ($data as $key => $lotnumber)
    {
        $stmt->execute($key);
    }
    $pdo->commit();
}catch (Exception $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

I have tried the whole day digging through the site to find an appropriate existing answer but have not been able to find one.

My question is if it is possible to do this and if yes what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: you have different number of elements in your arrays

Comment: sorry that was a typing error I corrected it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would get the correct occurance out of the 4 arrays and place them in the correct piece of the query, as long as there are always an equal number of occurances in all 4 arrays

```
$lot_number = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$serial_begin = array(1, 51, 101, 151, 201);
$serial_last = array(50, 100, 150, 200, 250);
$identifier = array('FA2567', 'FA2568', 'FA2569', 'FA2570', 'FA2571');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO shares_fclass 
                            (lot_number, serial_begin, serial_last, identifier) 
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    foreach ($lot_number as $key => $lotnumber) {
        $stmt->execute([$lotnumber, $serial_begin[$key], $serial_last[$key] , $identifier[$key] ]);
    }
    $pdo->commit();
}catch (Exception $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me without the need for any merger or combining of arrays. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, only that you execute the query with the wrong parameters.

Also, there is no need for an extra `$data` variable.

```
$lotNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$serialBegin = [1, 51, 101, 151, 201];
$serialLast = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];
$identifier = ['FA2567', 'FA2568', 'FA2569', 'FA2570', 'FA2571'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO shares_fclass 
                        (lot_number, serial_begin, serial_last, identifier) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lotNumber); $i++) {
        $stmt->execute([
            $lotNumber[$i],
            $serialBegin[$i],
            $serialLast[$i],
            $identifier[$i]
        ]);
    }

    $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: for loops are inconvenient to type. foreach loop is much more handy.

Comment: @Matei Mihai Thanks a lot for your help, although answer number 1 worked better for me.  Regards